# Moving EE2.2 site to new server with EE3.3

Tags: upgrade

Hey I'm just looking for some advice and things to consider when moving an EE2.2 site to a new server with EE3.3.

So far, I have downloaded/uploaded all of the files on the site and have downloaded the database.  Next, I'm wondering if I just need to import the database or if the difference between 2.2 and 3.3 will provide some weird issues when doing this.  I have noticed the directory structure between these versions is different.  I'm interested to hear what you all think.  Thanks!

Comment: First, completely migrate the site to the new server and complete configuration testing so you know the new server is serving the application satisfactorily. Then, update EE, it will take care of schema changes itself.

Comment: Also, many add-ons are not EE3 compatible; audit your current addons completely and make sure there are EE3 versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  There are modules that are not compatible.  Does this basically mean I'll have to do some reworking of channels & templates while also incorporating new equivalent modules?  This is a huge site, so I'm just trying to get as clear of an idea as to how much work it will be.

Comment: Yeah it does. Depending on the modules; you are given two options: (A) rework your templates and implementation to not use those modules (easier to do before upgrade) (B) Launch an EE3 dev site and fork those modules and upgrade them (license permitting). EE2 to EE3 is not a fun jump if the site is huge.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  This will definitely be an interesting experience haha.